# How can I get the id and ip_address and add one more column user_id in ci_session table in Codeigniter and add one

Tags: php, codeigniter

1. how can I get the id (session id) from ci_session table
2. I added user_id field in ci_session table but I do not know how can I set and get this field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You could use the `$this->session->session_id` to get the session id.
2. You could use `$this->session->set_userdata('user_id','value');` to save `value` into `user_id` column, and `$this->session->userdata('user_id');` to retrieve that `value`.

Edit

If you still want to update the table column, you could using the old way :

```
$this->db->where('id', session_id());
$this->db->update($this->config->item('sess_save_path'), array('user_id'=>'1111'));
```

Comment: when I used this statement     $this->session->set_userdata('user_id','1111'); then this add user_id into data column = '__ci_last_regenerate|i:1548192765;user_id|s:6:"1111";'. I need user_id column = '1111'

Comment: Why not save it in the `data` column? If that's what you want, then you could do it by updating the table manually (via the standard update query), but then to get the record you have to use the standard `get` query too, so there's no point on storing it on the session table..